# Frustrated by close workflow: unable to navigate "back" in the close reasons dialog

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Suppose I'm reading an off-topic question that isn't horrible. In my mind, I can imagine *some* site where it might fit. I click on close, then I click on "some other site", but I don't see a good target.

And now I'm stuck.

All I can do it click on the "x" button that cancels the whole business.

Could I please have a"'back" button that returns to the list of off-topic reasons?

Comment: The breadcrumbs at the top of the dialog are links that will take you back.

Comment: +1 I think an explicit Back-Button would be much more clearer, than clicking on the Headers (Breadcrumbs).

Answer (score 8):

The breadcrumbs at the top of the dialog are links that will take you back in the dialog.

[image: breadcrumbs]

The flagging dialog works the same way:

[image: flagging breadcrumbs]